# Powershell: Combining variables

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and i have this question:

I made this function:

```
Function A_Function($a,$b){
    $d = $a + $b
    $d
}
A_Function "0","1"
```

The problem is, that this function gives this as output:

```
0
1
```

And I would like it to be on one line:

```
01
```

I tried things like:

```
$d = ($a + $b) #result: same a sabove
$d = (""+$a + $b+"") #result: 1 0, but i dont want that space inbetween
$d = "$a$b" #result: 1 0, but i dont want that space inbetween
```

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending an array and it will bind to $a only. In PowerShell you delimit arguments with a space. Try this way instead:

```
A_Function "0" "1"
```

Also note that you're adding two strings, the result will be "01" ant not 1, in case you wanted to add numbers.